# Subset rows by a column variable created on the fly with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using `data.table` to subset the rows of my data.table based on the frequency of a variable (only keeping rows when a value for the given column variable occurs over a threshold of times).

The code below works.  I like how it's all calculated on the fly without an intermediate assignment cluttering the namespace, but including `dt` inside of another `dt` seems un-data.table-like?  I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method improving elegance and/or performance.

Perhaps an approach where the the function (`.N`, `table`, `length` or otherwise) is in the J argument and the row subsetting based on these values is in the I argument of a single data.table call?

#### reference for the example

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
print(table(dt[,cyl]))
#  4  6  8 
# 11  7 14
```

#### data.table code

keeping just rows where any value of `cyl` occurs more than 10 times (4 and 8 cylinder cars in this case)

```
library('data.table')
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
dt[cyl %in% dt[,.N, by=cyl][N>10, cyl],]
```

Comment: You can do `dt[, if (.N>10) .SD, by=cyl]` or `dt[dt[,.I[.N>10],by=cyl]$V1]`. There's a feature request open for a `having` argument that might make this look cleaner: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788